# Should ts-node examine the baseUrl tsconfig.json property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-node

I'm using ts-node and in `tsconfig.json` I have `"baseUrl": "./src"`.  This way I can import a sibling in `src` without using `./`.  However ts-node does not seem to using the `baseUrl` property in resolving the sibling imports, so I get errors like this:

```
    > tsmochanyc@1.0.0 test /home/ole/Junk/tsmochanyc
    > mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts

    Error: Cannot find module 'hello'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
```

Curious whether this is a ts-node bug or whether I should be doing something different?

Comment: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/613

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated in the issue posted to ts-node [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) can be used for this.  I have a fully (But minimal) working example here.  If you want to try it out just:

```
git clone https://github.com/oleersoy/tsmochanyc
cd tsmochanyc
npm i
npm test
```

Look at the the `baseUrl` and `paths` propertis in `tsconfig.json` to see how the resolution works.  In this case they have been set so that `tsmochanyc` proxies `src/` this way the path mirrors the same paths that devs would use if `tsmochanyc` were an external dependency.